# Add a text in the background of a input file

Tags: html, css

I have this simple form for uploading files:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input id="holder" type="file" style="padding: 5px; width:100%; height:100px; border: 5px dashed #ccc">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e98b2w7s/

But now I need a way to add this text in the background inside the dotted area:

```
"or Drag and Drop your file here"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you can try with absolute positioning. Set position relative to the form, then play with absolute position of the input, and then add your text with any element you like next to the input.

Comment: It won't be easy to get the position right though, since this control looks so differently across browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You may do better to just set your styles to your form instead, in which case you can just give the [form itself the background image](https://codepen.io/codespent/pen/dKxYaX) for a bit of a cleaner solution:

**Edit**: Removed background image to show with text instead for a cleaner approach.

```css
form {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px dashed #ccc;
}

form h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <input id="holder" type="file">
  <h1>Drag &amp; Drop Files Here</h1>
</form>
```

You don't need to use a background image, however, you could just create an `h1` that says "Drag & Drop Here" and then use an SVG or FontAwesome to add the cloud and/or arrow icons.

Comment: I've updated my CodePen link to include the ``h1`` as well so you can see how that looks and decide which route you'd want to take. I'd personally choose programmatically creating the "image" as it'll be more responsive, faster, and give you more control over style.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned a question here I'm posting my answer

```js
$(function () {
    var dropZoneId = "drop-zone";
    var buttonId = "clickHere";
    var mouseOverClass = "mouse-over";

    var dropZone = $("#" + dropZoneId);
    var ooleft = dropZone.offset().left;
    var ooright = dropZone.outerWidth() + ooleft;
    var ootop = dropZone.offset().top;
    var oobottom = dropZone.outerHeight() + ootop;
    var inputFile = dropZone.find("input");
    document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        dropZone.addClass(mouseOverClass);
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;

        if (!(x < ooleft || x > ooright || y < ootop || y > oobottom)) {
            inputFile.offset({ top: y - 15, left: x - 100 });
        } else {
            inputFile.offset({ top: -400, left: -400 });
        }

    }, true);

    if (buttonId != "") {
        var clickZone = $("#" + buttonId);

        var oleft = clickZone.offset().left;
        var oright = clickZone.outerWidth() + oleft;
        var otop = clickZone.offset().top;
        var obottom = clickZone.outerHeight() + otop;

        $("#" + buttonId).mousemove(function (e) {
            var x = e.pageX;
            var y = e.pageY;
            if (!(x < oleft || x > oright || y < otop || y > obottom)) {
                inputFile.offset({ top: y - 15, left: x - 160 });
            } else {
                inputFile.offset({ top: -400, left: -400 });
            }
        });
    }

    document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
        $("#" + dropZoneId).removeClass(mouseOverClass);
    }, true);

})
```

```css
#drop-zone {
    /*Sort of important*/
    width: 300px;
    /*Sort of important*/
    height: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:100px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    border: 2px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 180px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

    #drop-zone input {
        /*Important*/
        position: absolute;
        /*Important*/
        cursor: pointer;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        /*Important This is only comment out for demonstration purposes.
        opacity:0; */
    }

    /*Important*/
    #drop-zone.mouse-over {
        border: 2px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }


/*If you dont want the button*/
#clickHere {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #3b85c3;

}

    #clickHere:hover {
        background-color: #4499DD;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop-zone">
    or Drag and Drop files here
    <div id="clickHere">
        or click here..
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in this way, if I drag and drop the file, then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution

```
<form action="youractionfile.php" method="POST">
 <input type="file" multiple>
 <p>Drag your files here or click in this area.</p>
 <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
form{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -100px;
 margin-left: -250px;
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 4px dashed #fff; 
}
form p{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 170px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Arial;
}
form input{
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 outline: none;
 opacity: 0;
}
form button{
 margin: 0;
 color: #fff;
 background: #16a085;
 border: none;
 width: 508px;
 height: 35px;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-left: -4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #117A60;
 transition: all .2s ease;
 outline: none;
}
form button:hover{
background: #149174;
color: #0C5645;
}
form button:active{
 border:0;
}
</style>
```

below javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form input').change(function () {
   $('form p').text(this.files.length + " file(s) selected");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<input id="holder" type="file" placeholder="or Drag and Drop your file here" />
 <label for="holder"> or Drag and Drop your file here </label>
```

Css:

```
 [type=file] {
 position: absolute;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
}
   input,
[type=file] + label {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Js:

```
 $("[type=file]").on("change", function(){
  // Name of file and placeholder
  var file = this.files[0].name;
  var dflt = $(this).attr("placeholder");
  if($(this).val()!=""){
    $(this).next().text(file);
  } else {
    $(this).next().text(dflt);
  }
});
```

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/nopr/pen/rpsnd). Hope this work